# Scrape MP4 link in <video> tag, from a twitch clip, without using selenium? (Too slow)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Not using the Twitch API, by the way.

Is there any way I can use requests and beautifulsoup4 to scrape the link?

I want to scrape the <video> tag that actually contains the "src" attribute for the clip. But the problem is, whenever I try to load the page and use requests + beautifulsoup4 to look for the <video> tag, it doesn't show up for some reason. So someone recommended me to use Selenium.

Knowing that, I used selenium to code this: (But it takes way too long for my liking)

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


def get_clip_link(link):
    try:
        url = link
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(3)
        page = driver.page_source
        driver.quit()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        videos = soup.find_all('video')

        for video in videos:
            src = video['src']
            if src:
                return src
            else:
                return False
    except:
        return False
```

Is there anyway someone can help me figure out how would I go about getting the <video> tag after the page has loaded in without using selenium? Because it just takes too long and if the `time.sleep(3)` is any less, it doesn't find the <video> tag.

Also, here is a [twitch clip](https://clips.twitch.tv/DrabRelatedHerringWTRuck) if anyone wants to inspect element and check out the <video> tag.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're not using the API?

Comment: I have no idea how to use API's. I tried to look for some help on how to use twitch API but can't find any.

Comment: Have you considered using youtube-dl? Despite its name it can handle Twitch and it's as simple as `youtube-dl "https://clips.twitch.tv/DrabRelatedHerringWTRuck"`

Comment: I haven't but I don't need to download the clip, I just need to get the MP4 link in the video element relatively fast, so I can pass that URL into my flask website (JINJA2 template), so others can view it. Also, I got it to work, but it is very slow, so  now I am looking for a faster option.

Comment: `youtube-dl --get-url "https://clips.twitch.tv/DrabRelatedHerringWTRuck"` will print out the mp4 url and is speedy. You can pass multiple urls in one go & it's up to you how you capture the output e.g. stream to file or pipe output to another running process.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that. I am going to try that out. Thank you!

Comment: You can embed it as well if you really need - https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl